# calling a dict object / printing dict keys with value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dict objects called results in the following format:

```
{('AAPL', 'AAPL'): 1.0,
 ('AAPL', 'ABBV'): 0.2895481094217945,
 ('AAPL', 'AMZN'): 0.7985187751534586,
 ('AAPL', 'BAC'): 0.5923872592768968,
 ('AAPL', 'BRK-B'): 0.6076448647592143,
 ('AAPL', 'COST'): 0.6723253260025647,
 ('AAPL', 'CVX'): 0.2808264364499576,
 ('AAPL', 'GOOG'): 0.7932767338793895,
......
```

I want to filter through this result list to find values larger than 0.8
For this purpose I am using the following code:

```
i = 0

for i in results:
        if results[i] > 0.8:
            print(results[i])
```

This gives me the following output:

```
1.0
0.8506229861474826
0.9999999999999998
1.0
0.8269262016223845
0.8266345202049308
.......
```

Now in my output I want to also see the ticker combination from my dict list.

I have tried using:

```
print(results[ticker][I])
```

which gives me the error:

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Also I have tried using:

```
keys = results.keys()
for loop
print(results[keys[i]][I])
```

Which gave me the error:

> TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Using the code `results.keys()`

gives me the required keys:

```
dict_keys([('AAPL', 'AAPL'), ('AAPL', 'ABBV'), ('AAPL', 'AMZN'), ('AAPL', 'BAC'), ('AAPL', 'BRK-B'), ('AAPL', 'COST'), ('AAPL', 'CVX') ...
```

Now my only problem is getting the key combination with the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already iterating over the keys, so just print the key as you're going.

```
for key in results:
    if results[key] > 0.8:
        print(key, results[key])
```

Alternatively, and more Pythonically, use `results.items()` so you don't need to access the dict twice:

```
for key, result in results.items():
    if result > 0.8:
        print(key, result)
```